# jquery css with object container

Tags: jquery, object

I've probleme with

```
$pagContainer = $(sets.lists.container); // container: 'cart'
$bg = $($pagContainer + " li").css("background", "#FFFFFF");
$bg1 = $($pagContainer + " li:nth-child(2n)").css("background", "#767676");
```

I don't know if I need to put "#" before the $pagContainer like:

```
$pagContainer = $(sets.lists.container); // container: 'cart'
$bg = $("#" + $pagContainer + " li").css("background", "#FFFFFF");
```

or something like that.

who can be help me with this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sets.lists.container` contains a reference to a DOM element, or a selector in the form `#my_id`, then `$pagContainer` will already be a jQuery object, and cannot be used as a selector. In this case, you can use `.find`:

```
$pagContainer.find("li")
$pagContainer.find("li:nth-child(2n)")
```

Comment: hum doesn't work
my object is:
    lists {
      id: null,
      container: 'carts'
    }
    var sets = {};
    sets.init($this);
and $(sets.lists.container) exist in object.
but I don't know how i can use it..

Comment: Then, if 'carts' is the ID for your container, your first line should be `$pagContainer = $('#'+sets.lists.container);`. The following lines can use `.find()` on `$pagContainer` as I explained on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will use `'#'` if `$pagContainer` is the ID of an element, as in:

```
<div id='container_id'>
  <ul>
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

if `$pagContainer` value is `'container_id'` then the result selector would be `$('#container_id li')`. 
If you were trying to change the background of the list items, your syntax is correct, if you are trying to change the background of the div element just drop the last 'li'.

if `$pagContainer` is a class, use a `'.'` instead of a `'#'`